# Find a specific special character in a string- Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to find special characters if present other than `'` (apostrophe) and `-` (hyphen) in a String. Could some one tell how can I do that? The below outputs string with all the special characters.

```
select Test1 from test_table where test1 ~* '[^a-z0-9]';
```

I want to find special characters like in the below strings:

```
Moδ
Barφa m
zndrΘs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that would simply be

```
where test1 ~* '[^-''a-z0-9]'
```